# How to find out in C whether a double number has any digits after decimal point

Tags: c, algorithm, decimal, factorization

I stumbled on one issue while I was implementing in C the given algorithm:

```
int getNumberOfAllFactors(int number) {

  int counter = 0;
  double sqrt_num = sqrt(number);
  for (int i = 1; i <= sqrt_num; i++) {
      if ( number % i == 0) {
          counter = counter + 2;
      }
  }
  if (number == sqrt_num * sqrt_num)
      counter--;

  return counter;
}
```

– the reason for second condition – is to make a correction for perfect squares (i.e. 36 = 6 * 6), however it does not avoid situations (false positives) like this one:

```
sqrt(91) = 18.027756377319946
18.027756377319946 * 18.027756377319946 = 91.0
```

So my questions are: how to avoid it and what is the best way in C language to figure out whether a double number has any digits after decimal point? Should I cast square root values from double to integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you could test it like this:

```
if (sqrt_num == (int)sqrt_num)
```

Comment: Won't the RHS be converted to `double` again (implicit) before comparison?

Comment: @CinCout That won't be a problem, the decimal part has already been discarded when casting to `int`.

Comment: Yeah. Makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use the `modf()` family of functions:

> ```
> #include <math.h>
> double modf(double value, double *iptr);
> ```
>
> The `modf` functions break the argument value into integral and fractional parts, each of
>   which has the same type and sign as the argument. They store the integral part (in
>   floating-point format) in the object pointed to by `iptr`.

This is more reliable than trying to use direct conversions to `int` because an `int` is typically a 32-bit number and a `double` can usually store far larger integer values (up to 53 bits worth) so you can run into errors unnecessarily.  If you decide you must use a conversion to `int` and are working with `double` values, at least use `long long` for the conversion rather than `int`.

(The other members of the family are `modff()` which handles `float` and `modfl()` which handles `long double`.)

Comment: @wintermute "**best** way in C language to figure out whether a double number has any digits after decimal point?" --> use `modf()`.  Using `int()` or `sqrt(number)` limits the range of detecting "any digits after decimal point" in `double` via other methods.